# How do I make Gmail inbox display the contact names as I saved them in Google Contacts?

Tags: gmail, google-contacts, email-headers

The thing is no matter how well completed, how detailed we have our contacts stored, Gmail seems to display the default name the senders set up in their clients or mail services.

This creates confusion when people only have a nickname set up as their default mail, or especially when we have an email stored that is associated to a different person.

This is a very common situation for us as we work in health and deal with a lot of older patients and very frequently they don't have a personal email or no means of checking it so they usually give us their son / daughter ´s (or brother, nephew, random relative - you get the idea).

We deal with a large database and we recently added an email confirmation system for appointments which seems to be working very well and people are very happy with, but it is very frustrating not being able to set up Gmail to display the contact name as stored -i.e. our patient´s name, and having to track who that mail corresponds to in our patient database.

Seems it should be something you should be able to set up to your liking or convenience but I haven't been able to find the way.

Comment: Sometimes this can happen when you have a duplicate contact for the person in "Other contacts". If you haven't already, check here and see if there is a duplicate for one of the people whose name doesn't show up the way you expect: https://contacts.google.com/other

Comment: The described by the question behaviour occurs even if the contact is not duplicated e.g. in "other contacts" section.